# Can't delete filename with invalid character windows 10

Tags: file, windows-10, invalid-characters, long-filenames

[Filename has invalid character ][1]

Comment: Please take the time to format your question properly. Just posting links to images isn't going to get you any answers ... 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Windows explorer: the command prompt has limited ability for displaying and handling strange characters, hence the usage of the Windows explorer is advised for such matters.

As mentioned in the [ServerFault URL](https://serverfault.com/questions/95581/delete-file-containing-invalid-characters-in-windows#:~:text=Now%2C%20Open%20the%20drive%20properties.&text=Then%2C%20go%20to%20%22Tools%22,under%20'Error%20checking'%20label.&text=This%20will%20unmount%20your%20drive,such%20files%20with%20illegal%20names.), you might do the following:

```
chkdsk /F
Reboot the PC
Use the Windows explorer again for deleting the file
```

Comment: ServerFault URL: https://serverfault.com/questions/95581/delete-file-containing-invalid-characters-in-windows#:~:text=Now%2C%20Open%20the%20drive%20properties.&text=Then%2C%20go%20to%20%22Tools%22,under%20'Error%20checking'%20label.&text=This%20will%20unmount%20your%20drive,such%20files%20with%20illegal%20names.